# Search bar missing when copying test cases in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, copy, test-plan

When I copy a test case in DevOps, a popup opens to select a test plan.  When you click the dropdown to select a test plan, there used to be a search bar to filter down the list.  Now that search bar is missing.  We did a new install of DevOps recently and something has changed.  Not sure if it's a setting.  I created an issue in the Visual Studio Developer Community and have someone who is responding to me but I'm not sure he understands the issue or even how to get the information from me that he needs.  It's been tedious.  Anyway, hoping someone here can help.
[Search popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6rR0.png)

Here is a screenshot of the searchbar that I'm missing.
[Search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBRUQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The search bar only displays after you have more than 10 Test Plans created.

Not a great UX and, of course, no documentation around this.  And the MS customer support clearly don't even know about it.

Answer (score 0):

So far, there is no search bar to filter test plans when copy test case. No update made recently on it.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

Comment: There was as of August of this year.  As I mentioned, I have reached out to the developer community and am in communication with someone but it's been frustrating.

Comment: @apetrone, I have checked in multiple ADO organizations, never see the search bar was existing. This feature should be not supported currently. You might just open a feedback ticket instead of a feature request on Developer Community. It is recommended opening a feature request for your demands.

Comment: That is not true.  I have a screenshot of it on a current installation (with another company)

Comment: @apetrone, Can you please show it?

Comment: I just added it to my original question

Comment: Well, I thought I did.  Hold on let me try that again.

Comment: It's in review.

Comment: I think it's there now.

Comment: did you see the screenshot?

Comment: You just ghosted me :)